# Invoking findViewById on a null object. Which isn't null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a settings fragment which contains, well, settings.

On line 22 I have a findview which finds a textview. It worked wonders until today (Didn't change a thing). Now I imagine it will also fail the rest of the finds but since it crashes on this one, we will never know.

Why is that?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a8a4a1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="ACCOUNT"
        android:textColor="#2b2a29"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentAccountSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Account Settings"
        android:textColor="#2b2a29"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#a8a4a1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="THEME"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentAccountSettings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Dark Mode"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentDarkModeSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:scaleX="1.25"
        android:scaleY="1.25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentAccountSettings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#a8a4a1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="OTHER"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentDarkModeSwitch" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentFAQ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="FAQ"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/r" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentSupport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Support"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentFAQ" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentPolicy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Content Policy &amp; EULA"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentSupport" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentUSerAgreement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="User Agreement"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentPolicy" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentBugReport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Report A Bug"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentUSerAgreement" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Build"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#a8a4a1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="BUILD INFORMATION"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SettingsFragmentBugReport" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="1.0.0"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.042"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Build" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragment code:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Settings extends Fragment {
    TextView accSettings, FAQ, BugReport, Policy, UserAgg, Support;
    Switch darkModeSwitch;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        accSettings = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentAccountSettings);  <--- This one
        FAQ = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentFAQ);
        BugReport = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentBugReport);
        Policy = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentPolicy);
        UserAgg = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentUSerAgreement);
        Support = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentSupport);
        darkModeSwitch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentDarkModeSwitch);
        accSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AccountSettings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        BugReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BugReport.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        FAQ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDiag();
            }
        });
        Policy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDiag();
            }
        });
        UserAgg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDiag();
            }
        });
        Support.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDiag();
            }
        });

        darkModeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                /*
                In here, put 0 into MySqli DB if the isChecked value = False.
                Put 1 into MySqli DB if the isChecked value = 1.
                 */
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
    }
    void alertDiag(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("Well here we are")
                .setMessage("Normally, the user by now would've gone into a website explaining the content of the pressed TextView.\n"
                + "Since we do not have a website or a domain, we show this AlertDialog. Sorry for the turnout!")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Now I imagine it will also fail the rest of the finds but since it crashes on this one, we will never know." You know you can just change the order of the findViewById() or comment lines.

Comment: Move everything but the `inflate()` call *out* of `onCreateView()` and move it into `onViewCreated()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do on the first line of onCreateView:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
```

Then do for each of your findViewById:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
```

You're inflating the view last instead of first.

Then at the end of onCreateView():

```
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below way to initialize and return in your oncreateview

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    
      View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
    
    //Init all here like 
    accSettings = (TextView) view. findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentAccountSettings)
    
      //and then return like
      return view;
    }
```

Hope it may help you